# How to return properly with both chained and a default function

Tags: javascript

The tutorials I have seen by searching would leave me with an undesireable format like

```
main.default('word');
main.default('word').chain();
```

where as I want to do

```
main('word');
main('word').chain();
```

> This code is just for a console.log() example to see if I can carry the word through. log 'word' or log 'chained word'

If I `return this;` then I can chain:

```
var main = function(input){

    this.input = input;

    this.chain = function(){
        this.chained='chained '+this.input;
        return this.chained;
        }

    this.default = function(){
        return this.input;
        }

    return this;
};

console.log(main('word').chain());  //'chained word'
```

But, I can't do `console.log(main('word').chain().chain());` I think from what I have read because the chained function does not return `this`, instead it returns `this.chained`

Then if I do `return this.default();` inside the `main` function, the default action I want `main` to perform happens

```
var main = function(input) {


    this.input = input;


    this.chain = function() {
        this.chained = 'out '+this.input;
        return this.chained;
    }

    this.default = function() {
        return this.input;
    }

    return this.default();
};

console.log(main('word'));     //'word'
```

I have also been looking through jquerys core file to see If I can pick out how they did it with the jQuery function but I really can't see what is going on there.

Comment: in your case `this` is global object: _window_

Comment: so what you want exactly?

Comment: What tutorial have you read? To chain, you of course need to use `return this;` (no property)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to archive:

```
main('word').chain().chain().chain().getInput();
// resulting in 'chained chained chained word'
```

Try to return *this* all time, not a string as in code of the question.
Now you can modify the inner variables, but need a get...() function to access them from outside.

```js
var main = function(input) {

  this.input = input;

  this.chain = function() {
    this.input = 'chained ' + this.input;
    return this;
  }

  this.getInput = function() {
    return this.input;
  }

  return this;
};

var valueString = main('word').chain().chain().chain().getInput(); //'chained chained chained word'
document.querySelector('#result').value = valueString;
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
result:
<input id="result" />
```

Comment: +1 very cool  I would not have figured out these combinations by guessing.. This page is getting starred!

Comment: in your sample when you call simple `main` in `window` object will be added property _input_, and functions _chain_ and _getInput_, also when you do _return this_ you return _window_ object in your case

Comment: I will check this _window object_ later on.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I needed here: http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/

And just incase that site ever goes away...

> **Implementing our own chaining API** To simplify things, if we remove some of the layers, here's how would we can implement the skeleton of
>   the jQuery constructor function to provide a simple chaining API.
>
> ```
> var myQuery, $;
>
> (function() {
>
>     myQuery = $ = function(selector) {
>         return new MyQuery(selector);
>     };
>
>     var MyQuery = function(selector) {
>         // Lets make a really simplistic selector implementation for demo purposes
>         var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
>         for (var i = 0; i &lt; nodes.length; i++) {
>             this[i] = nodes[i];
>         }
>         this.length = nodes.length;
>         return this;
>     };
>
>     // Expose the prototype object via myQuery.fn so methods can be added later
>     myQuery.fn = MyQuery.prototype = {
>         // API Methods
>         hide: function() {
>             for (var i = 0; i &lt; this.length; i++) {
>                 this[i].style.display = 'none';
>             }
>             return this;
>         },
>         remove: function() {
>             for (var i = 0; i &lt; this.length; i++) {
>                 this[i].parentNode.removeChild(this[i]);
>             }
>             return this;
>         }
>         // More methods here, each using 'return this', to enable chaining
>     };
>
> }());
>
> // Example usage
> $('p').hide().remove();
>
> // Add a plugin
> $.fn.red = function() {
>     for (var i = 0; i &lt; this.length; i++) {
>         this[i].style.color = 'red';
>     }
>     return this;
> }
>
> $('li').red();
> ```